# Utilization TIdSASLLogin for TIdTCPServer

Tags: indy10

Whether `indy SASL` component can use to `TIdTCPServer` and `TIdTCPCLient`?
if can, please give me advice how the algorithm to handle that ?
Do I have to use `TIdSMTP` too ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Indy's SASL components are client-side components only.  There are no server-side SASL implementations available in Indy at this time.  You would have to implement server-side SASL manually.  The SASL components are designed primarily to be used with the `TIdSASLCollection` class, which is used by the `TIdSMTP`, `TIdPOP3`, and `TIdIMAP4` components.  Have a look at the source code for those components to see how to incorporate SASL into your client code.